# Get Second/Third Best Hyperparameters for comparison (keras tuner)

Tags: python, keras-tuner

i want to ask about keras tuner method. I know that get_best_hyperparameters() return the value of the best hyperparameters. How about a method to return the second/third/etc best hyperparameters. Is there any other method to use to get their value?

I only tried get_best_hyperparameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Keras API Reference](https://keras.io/api/keras_tuner/tuners/base_tuner/):

> **Returns**
>
> List of HyperParameter objects sorted from the best to the worst.

Use `[1]`, `[2]`, etc. on the return value.

Comment: when i use [1] or [2] example : "tuner.get_best_hyperparameters()[1]". It said " list index out of range"

Comment: Did you read about the optional parameter `num_trials`?

Comment: Ohh yeah.. i just realize i need to use it together.. thanks for the answer